# Why is the wallet-GUI Payment ID field not accepting an ID?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id

Wallet GUI 10.3.1
Linux Mint 18.1, 64 bit

**Send** and **Address book** tab appear to reject any payment ID I put in there. **Send** will only allow me to send when there is no payment ID.

EDIT:  If I recall, the application is in beta. Is this something that I should merely report as a bug on github? I have not used the wallet until now.

Comment: Is the payment id you're attempting to use 64 characters long and composed only of hexadecimal (0-9 and a-f)?

Comment: 16 and 64 (and anything in between, if I try it). I'm using `openssl rand -hex 8` and `openssl rand -hex 32`. The Payment ID boxes are inconsistent across the program. Send has 16/64. Receives says 16. Address book says 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs with integrated addresses. Because it already contains a payment ID, it rejects any additional IDs by the user.

106 character integrated address (causes the Payment ID to fail).

95 character normal address (does not cause a problem with the Payment ID).